# Doing a Range Query over particular Nested Document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a document structure like this. For this below two documents, we have nested documents called interaction info. I just need to get only the documents that have title **duration** and their value is greater than **60**

```
  {
    "key": "f07ff9ba-36e4-482a-9c1c-d888e89f926e",
    "interactionInfo": [
      {
        "title": "duration",
        "value": "11"
      },
      {
        "title": "timetaken",
        "value": "9"
      },
      {
        "title": "talk_time",
        "value": "145"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "f07ff9ba-36e4-482a-9c1c-d888e89f926e",
    "interactionInfo": [
      {
        "title": "duration",
        "value": "120"
      },
      {
        "title": "timetaken",
        "value": "9"
      },
      {
        "title": "talk_time",
        "value": "60"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it possible to get only the document that has **title: duration** and their value is greater than 60.Value Property in the nested Document is text and keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few basic mistakes in your solution, in order to utilize the range query(ie find a document which has more than 60 value, you need to store them as an integer in your case).

Also please refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) official guide which has a similar example.

Let me show you a step-by-step example on how to do it.

### Index def

```
{
    "mappings" :{
        "properties" :{
            "interactionInfo" :{
                "type" : "nested"
            },
            "key" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
    "key": "f07ff9ba-36e4-482a-9c1c-d888e89f926e",
    "interactionInfo": [
      {
        "title": "duration",
        "value": 120. --> note, not using `""` double quotes which would store them as integer
      },
      {
        "title": "timetaken",
        "value": 9
      },
      {
        "title": "talk_time",
        "value": 60
      }
    ]
  }


{
    "key": "f07ff9ba-36e4-482a-9c1c-d888e89f926e",
    "interactionInfo": [
        {
            "title": "duration",
            "value": 11
        },
        {
            "title": "timetaken",
            "value": 9
        },
        {
            "title": "talk_time",
            "value": 145
        }
    ]
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "interactionInfo",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "interactionInfo.title": "duration"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "interactionInfo.value": {
                                    "gt": 60
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And your expected search result**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "nestedsoint",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 2.0296195,
        "_source": {
          "key": "f07ff9ba-36e4-482a-9c1c-d888e89f926e",
          "interactionInfo": [
            {
              "title": "duration",
              "value": 120
            },
            {
              "title": "timetaken",
              "value": 9
            },
            {
              "title": "talk_time",
              "value": 60
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply opster, I already aware that rage query won't support for the text field. But we have already stored a lot of documents as value as String, not as Integer. Is there any possible way to do a range query on text fields Like applying Script or painless query.

Comment: Hi, opster again thank you for your time to reply. but I already mentioned at the bottom of the question as the value field is text and keyword. Yeah, it is my mistakes not to mentioned it properly.

Comment: @Thilak, sorry I just woke-up and if you see the original question it wasn't mentioned in the begining, check this by clicking the edit history in the question. you are new to the community and it's OK to miss some things, but you should also understand that community is helping you and I've invested quite some time to make it work and as explained in my previous comment, still it would be very useful answer hence don't want to modify the answer and its a standard to ask another follow-up question if you have new requirements and would be more than happy to help you further 

Comment: Okay opster will do a followup